# chrome webdriver set viewport below 500px?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

In my selenium based tests, I am setting the window size to 400(w) 719(h) to create an internal viewport size of 400x640. Most of my tests are based on that size though some use other sizes.

```java
Dimension size = new Dimension(400, 719);
driver.manage().window().setSize(size);
```

More recent versions of chrome fail to set the window size to 400 pixels width, instead, the resulting window width is around 500px (though it varies).

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2639
(bug, claims its fixed, but seems not)

So instead I want to set the internal viewport size.

How do I do this in selenium/chrome webdriver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at chromedriver [Moblie Emulation](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/mobile-emulation).

As mentioned there,

java example

```java
Map<String, Object> deviceMetrics = new HashMap<>();
deviceMetrics.put("width", 360);
deviceMetrics.put("height", 640);
deviceMetrics.put("pixelRatio", 3.0);

Map<String, Object> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
mobileEmulation.put("deviceMetrics", deviceMetrics);
mobileEmulation.put("userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19");

ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this.

Comment: This solved it for me thanks. I still have a test that resizes the window during the test, and that won't work for the smaller sizes still, which the above does not solve, but I will just drop the resize tests for the smaller sizes that don't work.