# Selenium Window Size Not Changing While Using Device Emulation

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I'm trying to change the window size using chrome option while using device emulation but it has no impact on width but works for height.

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=400,600")
chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
mobile_emulation = { "deviceName": "iPhone 6/7/8 Plus" }
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
```

also tried

```
browser.set_window_size(400, 600)
```

is there something missing? or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can not set a selenium driver window width to 400.
AFAIK minimal computer screen width is 512.
To use smaller window width you can simulate mobile device screen sizes.
There are several discussions about this issue, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56054665/chrome-webdriver-set-viewport-below-500px)